# fade in effect jquery with delay and css animations

Tags: jquery, css, animation, delay, fade

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
    $('#list-item-1').delay(500).addClass('animated fadeInRight');
    $('#list-item-2').delay(1000).addClass('animated fadeInRight');
    $('#list-item-3').delay(1500).addClass('animated fadeInRight');
    $('#list-item-4').delay(2000).addClass('animated fadeInRight');
    $('#list-item-5').delay(2500).addClass('animated fadeInRight');
    $('#list-item-6').delay(3000).addClass('animated fadeInRight');
```

But all the items fade in from the right at the same time. I don't understand why

Comment: You might want to add the css for animated and fadeInRight classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `delay()` has no effect on `addClass()`, you should work with `setTimeout`

**EXAMPLE**

`setTimeout(function(){$('#list-item-1').addClass('animated fadeInRight');}, 500);`

Comment: You forgot the $ sign. But thank you very much, now it's perfect

Answer (score 0):

`delay()` only works for effects queues.  `addClass()` is not an effect queue.  You would need to use something like `slideUp()` etc to have the delay work like this.

Answer (score 0):

try with setTimeout function.

https://www.udemy.com/blog/jquery-settimeout/